# Google Guava's CacheLoader loadAll() vs reload() semantics

Tags: java, caching, guava

Two things I really like about Guava 11's CacheLoader (thanks, Google!) are loadAll(), which allows me to load multiple keys at once, and reload(), which allows me to reload a key asynchronously when it's "stale" but an old value exists.  I'm curious as to how they play together, since reload() operates on but a single key.

Concretely, extending the example from [CachesExplained](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained):

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .maximumSize(1000)
   .refreshAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
         public Graph load(Key key) { // no checked exception
           return getGraphFromDatabase(key);
         }

         public Map<Key, Graph> loadAll(Iterable<? extends K> keys) {
           return getAllGraphsFromDatabase(keys);
         }

         public ListenableFuture<Graph> reload(final Key key, Graph prevGraph) {
           if (neverNeedsRefresh(key)) {
             return Futures.immediateFuture(prevGraph);
           } else {
             // asynchronous!
             return ListenableFutureTask.create(new Callable<Graph>() {
               public Graph call() {
                 return getGraphFromDatabase(key);
               }
             });
           }
         }
       });
```

...where "getAllGraphsFromDatabase()" does an aggregate database query rather than length(keys) individual queries.

How do these two components of a LoadingCache play together?  If some keys in my request to getAll() aren't present in the cache, they are loaded as a group with loadAll(), but if some need refreshing, do they get reloaded individually with load()?  If so, are there plans to support a reloadAll()?

Comment: [Cache.getAll fails to trigger refresh #971](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/971) is still open to vote

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's how refreshing works.

Refreshing on a cache entry can be triggered in two ways:

1. Explicitly, with `cache.refresh(key)`.
2. Implicitly, if the cache is configured with `refreshAfterWrite` and the entry is *queried* after the specified amount of time after it was written.

If an entry that is eligible for reload is queried, then the old value is returned, and a (possibly asynchronous) refresh is triggered.  The cache will continue to return the old value for the key while the refresh is in progress.  (So if some keys in a `getAll` request are eligible for refresh, their old values will be returned, but the values for those keys will be (possibly asynchronously) reloaded.)

The *default* implementation of `CacheLoader.reload(key, oldValue)` just returns `Futures.immediateFuture(load(key))`, which (synchronously) recomputes the value.  More sophisticated, asynchronous implementations are recommended if you expect to be doing cache refreshes.

I don't think we're inclined to provide `reloadAll` at the moment.  I suspect it's possible, but things are complicated enough as it is, and I think we're inclined to wait until we see specific demand for such a thing.

Comment: I knew you guys are all over the Overflow, which is why I figured I'd ask here.  Thanks!  So, if I make a getAll() call, I can have potentially three types of keys.  Those that are present (and fresh) in the cache, those that are not in the cache at all, and those that are present (and ready for a refresh).  Those that are present are returned from the cache, those that are not present are pulled in via my loadAll() function, and those that are present in the cache but ready for a refresh have the old values returned but then are reloaded one by one, asynchronously?  Is that correct?

Comment: Well, "one by one" and "asynchronous" wouldn't be the terminology I use, but I'm pretty sure that you've got it right.  (Though elements will be refreshed individually, their refreshes will be _concurrent_.)

Comment: Thank you!  Is there a way to control how many concurrent refreshes occur so I don't DoS my database?  If I ask my cache for 100 keys, I want to avoid making 90 parallel individual database requests to refresh the stale values when a single query to fetch them all would suffice.

Comment: When you're implementing `reload`, create the returned `ListenableFuture` on a `ListeningExecutorService` with a fixed number of threads.  That'll limit the number of concurrently executing queries.

Comment: FYI, I'm going to file an issue with Guava just to make sure it gets discussed.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you very much!  If I had more upvotes on this answer, I'd use them.

Comment: @spitzanator You could aggregate the `reload` requests yourself by filling a queue connected to a worker pool. Each worker would drain the queue instead of just taking a single element. This might need introducing some delay in between, but should be rather simple.

Comment: Oh, good idea!  You'd have to make sure that multiple requests to the cache didn't add duplicate elements to the queue, though...

Comment: Either this or ignore them when draining. According to the javadoc for `LoadingCache.refresh` I'd guess the implementor must take care of this. However, it should be easy.